# Show that for M symmetric positive definite have $\sup_{||x||=1}\langle x, Mx \rangle$=$\lambda_1=:$ the largest eigenvalue of M

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that if I can reach the step
$$\sup_{||x||=1}\langle x, Mx \rangle=\langle x,\lambda_1 x\rangle$$ then clearly $\lambda_1$ follows. But how can we bridge this gap?

Comment: The key word to search is "Rayleigh quotient". See also: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/notes_linear.pdf

Comment: Or alternatively, consider $\varphi(t) = f(x + ty)$, where $f(x) = \left(Mx\middle|x\right)/(x|x)$. Then $\varphi(t)$ attains maximum at $t=0$, thus the differential calculus would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the spectral theorem we can take an $\textit{orthonormal basis}$ of $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $M$, say $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then, for any $\Vert v\Vert=1$ we can write $v=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n$. Try expanding $\langle Mv,v\rangle$ using linearity of the inner product, the fact that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{i,j}$, and the fact that $Mv_i=\lambda_iv_i$ to show that $\langle Mv,v\rangle\leq\lambda^*$ where $\lambda^*$ is your max eigenvalue. Then can you exhibit a specific $v$ with norm $1$ for which equality holds (think eigenvectors)?

Comment: Thank you. The orthogonal basis was the key. $||v||=1 \Rightarrow \sum_{i}^{n} c_i^2=1$ then write $\langle v, Mv \rangle= \sum_i^n \lambda_i c_i^2 \leq \sum_i^n \lambda_1 c_i^2 = \lambda_1$